# Dropdownlist in a edit.blade.php form

Tags: laravel

please how can I put dropdown list in an edit form with the old selected value on default?

here is my example:

```
<div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Container', 'Container:') }}
        {{ Form::select('Select_cont', $containers) }}
     </div>
```

I don´t know where to put the code of the old new value selected in my view and what should it be.
Please don´t forget that when directing to edit.blade.php I wrote thisin the function of my controller

```
 return View::make('audio.edit',array($container))
->with('containers', $containers)
```

thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: If you use `Form::model()` then you should be able to do `Input::old(Select_cont)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selected value is the 3rd param of Form::select, so:

```
{{ Form::select('Select_cont', $containers, $selectedPreviouslyKey) }}
```

How to get that key depends on your code and what's in the dropdown

Pass it to the view like this

```
return View::make('audio.edit',array('containers' => $containers, 'selectedPreviouslyKey' => $selectedKey));
```

or use compact() / with etc

Comment: Thanks firstly for your answer but how should I redirect $selectedPreviouslyKey with the view?

Comment: Thanks again but selectedPreviouslyKey what should it be?

Comment: I will add for you some explanation: $containers in my case is $containers = DB::table('containers')->distinct()->lists('Container'); and $selectedPreviouslyKey=containers::with ('profiles')
   ->join('profiles', 'profiles.idcontainer', '=', 'containers.id')
   ->select('containers.Container')
   ->where('profiles.id','=',$audioprofile->id)->get(); with idcontainer it´s a foreign key in profiles! thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I think you misunderstand ORM conception here, why you even join profiles if you already eager loaded them? Edit your question and describe what you want to retrieve and what are relationships between yuor models

Comment: I have a table profiles(id,#idcontainer...)which is related to a table containers(id,Container)
Then in my edit view I have to edit the dropdownlist which shows all Container from containers which is defined by $_containers. I want to show this list of Container *with the old selected Container* defined by $container

Comment: Show the code from your controller and models relations, otherwise it's just guessing what you want...

Comment: I decidedto not show the old selected value :) I thinkk it's complicated:

Answer (score 0):

The View::make call isn't entirely right. It should be:

```
return View::make('audio.edit')->with('containers', $containers);
```

or

```
return View::make('audio.edit')->withContainers($containers);
```

or

```
return View::make('audio.edit', array('containers' => $containers));
```

or

```
return View::make('audio.edit', compact('containers'));
```

Also: make sure `$containers` exists.

The documentation on the select tag. http://laravel.com/docs/html#drop-down-lists

Comment: Please approve the answer if you like.